# How do I restrain domain names of e-mails in the Drupal registration form?

Tags: users

On the registration page, I want to restrict the domain of the e-mail adress only between a few choices (to limit the use of the site to internal company use only) through a list of choices. **The user, upon registration, would therefore only have to write the characters before the @ sign ; and then choose the correct domain name he uses (for instance yahoo.fr).**
The final value of the email registered by Drupal (and thus registered in the database) should be like this one: [User_entry]+[@]+[chosen_domain_name].
I found some functions [to verify the e-mail spelling](http://drupal.org/node/755894), but I really want users only to have the choice between shown domain names.

I've read [some answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/theming-the-user-registration-form) talking about `hook_form_user_login_alter()`, but I still don't get how I could make it...

Thks for your replies !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have any experience in PHP or custom module development but I don't have time to give you a working example.  However I will point you in the right direction.

• Create a [custom module](http://drupal.org/developing/modules)

• Use `hook_form_alter` to alter the form with the form id `user_registration`

• In your `hook_form_alter` add a custom validation function and ensure it is the first validation function that runs

• In your `hook_form_alter` unset the `mail` element and add two elements for the two parts of your form (the text input and the dropdown list of domains)

• In your custom validation function, use the submitted values of your form elements to create an email address and assign it to the element you unset before, `mail`

• Make sure that in the validation function, you don't allow users to submit blank values

**Edit for a fuller answer to be added**

Ok, apologies for taking my time.  This code is untested but should hopefully work for what you want to do.  First of all, try to avoid doing things like this in the theme layer.  The theme layer should be for themes only, so you want to create a custom module.

To create your module you need to create a `.info` file.  Alter the following code and paste it into your text editor and save it as `example.info`.  Remember that you can change the names of the files etc to whatever suits you, just replace the word "example" with whatever name you want to give it.  Please note that Drupal deliberately omits the closing `?>` PHP tag.

```
name = "Example module"
description = "Gives an example of a module."
core = 6.x
package = Other
```

Next, you want to save a file called `example.module`.  Inside this file, you will want to copy the following code.  This code follows the instructions that I gave you in my previous answer.  I have tried to comment this code as well as possible in order to try to show you what is being done and why.  This should do what you want it to do.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */
function example_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // If the form is the user_register form
    if ($form_id == 'user_register') {
        // Attach our custom validation function as the first validation function
        array_unshift($form['#validate'], '_example_user_validate');
        // Hide the email address field
        $form['mail']['#type'] = 'hidden';
        // Give the email address field a random default value (in this case a random number and a timestamp)
        // as we cannot unset it due to Drupal's validation rules
        $form['mail']['#default_value'] = rand(1111, 9999) . '@' .time() . '.com';
        // Add our new text entry field
        $form['mail_first'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Email address'),
      '#default_value' => '',
      '#size' => 60,
      '#maxlength' => 64,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
        // Add our select list of possible email domain values
        $form['mail_last'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#prefix' => '@',
      '#options' => array(
              // These are the possible email address domains
              'yahoo.fr' => 'yahoo.fr',
              'yahoo.com' => 'yahoo.com',
              'example.com' => 'example.com',
            ),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    }
}

/**
 * Function to piece together our email address
 */
function _example_user_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // If our two form elements have values
    if (!empty($form_state['values']['mail_first']) && !empty($form_state['values']['mail_last'])) {
        // Set the email address to the correct value
        $form_state['values']['mail'] = $form_state['values']['mail_first'] . '@' . $form_state['values']['mail_last'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thks a lot for your help ! I'll try to write this (I have a little experience in PHP), and post-it there either it works or not...!  :)

Comment: If you come up with code and it doesn't work, post it back here and we can take a look at it.

Comment: Well, as I thought what I tried didn't worked : I'm a very beginner at PHP coding and Drupal architecture frightens me a bit !

I post my function in answer to this question, so it's not limited.

Comment: BTW : tatheme is the name of my time, I've put that into my template.php

Comment: (I meant my theme, not my time ^^)

Comment: Answer now updated.

Comment: Thks for your module !  
I made it work in D7 by changing the form_id to user_register_form, and `$form['mail']` to `$form['account']['mail']`. **Do you think it's the good variables? Especially the $form_state one...**    (cf my edited answered for the whole updated code)

Comment: I tested it, there's a problem with $form_state variables I think : the newly registered user never received the message... I checked the user account : the registered e-mail adress was the string+timestamp one...

Comment: I'll have a look as I've not really coded modules for Drupal 7.  The code will need to be updated for Drupal 7 I think.

Comment: Well the display is all right since I added `['account']` but the registered e-mail remains the one made string+timestamp, I should print_r($form_state) to see which variables are available but I can't figure how (where and when to print it with the desired values)......

Comment: If you could do that and post it for me that would be great.  Add it just before the line that says `// If the form is the user_register form`.

Comment: ... Well, the result is very strange. I printed $form_state on the user registration form page and also $form . Here what it gave to me : [nyoz.fr/form.txt](http://nyoz.fr/form.txt)  and  [nyoz.fr/form_state.txt](http://nyoz.fr/form_state.txt)  

As you might see, mail-first and mail-last don't appear in the array, mail only appears in $form... I've also included the body content (at least the part which interest us).

So, doctor ?  ^^

Comment: Do you any clue then ?

Comment: HELP, please !    :/

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what the problem is and I'm not able to dedicate the time to it I'm afraid.  Try to Google user reg form alter etc.  If you look/try hard enough you'll get there.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I wrote, I think it's full of errors !  O_O   ^^

```
<?php 
    function tatheme_user_registration_form_alter (&$variables) {
        if (!empty($variables['user']['mail'])) {
            unset $variables['user']['mail'];
        }
        print '<input id="mailpart1" value="" class="'.$classes.'" type="text" /> @ <select id="mailpart2" name="mailpart2" class="'.$classes.'"><option value="dede.net">dede.net</option><option value="dede.com">dede.com</option>';

        $syntax='#^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$#'; 

        $mail = $_POST['mailpart1']+"@"+$_POST['mailpart2'];

        if (isset($_POST['mailpart1']) OR !$_POST['mailpart1']) {
            return false;
        }
        else {  
            if (preg_match($syntax,$mail)) {
                return true; 
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        $variables['user']['mail'] = $mail;
    }
    ?>
```

**CODE UPDATE AT 05/28/11 :**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */
function ta_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // If the form is the user_register form
    if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
        // Attach our custom validation function as the first validation function
        array_unshift($form['#validate'], '_ta_module_user_validate');
        // Hide the email address field
        $form['account']['mail']['#type'] = 'hidden';
        // Give the email address field a random default value (in this case a random number and a timestamp)
        // as we cannot unset it due to Drupal's validation rules
        $form['account']['mail']['#default_value'] = rand(1111, 9999) . '@' .time() . '.com';
        // Add our new text entry field
        $form['mail_first'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Email address'),
      '#default_value' => '',
      '#size' => 40,
      '#maxlength' => 64,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
        // Add our select list of possible email domain values
        $form['mail_last'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#prefix' => '@',
      '#options' => array(
              // These are the possible email address domains
              'blabla.net' => 'blabla.net',
              'blabla.com' => 'blabla.com',
            ),
      '#default_value' => 'blabla.net',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    }
}

/**
 * Function to piece together our email address
 */
function _ta_module_user_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // If our two form elements have values
    if (!empty($form_state['values']['mail_first']) && !empty($form_state['values']['mail_last'])) {
        // Set the email address to the correct value
        $form_state['values']['mail']['edit-mail'] = $form_state['values']['mail_first'] . '@' . $form_state['values']['mail_last'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos for trying to code it mate, even if you didn't get it right you still had a shot.  I'll post some code a bit later that should set you right. Well done.

Comment: Ok! Thks for your attention!