# Change the e-mail value during user registration ?  form_set_value()

Tags: 7, forms, users, emails

I have a custom module (entitled ta_module) : in the user registration form, it hides the e-mail field, and add a custom field where user have to enter what's before @ and then choose his e-mail domain name between the one proposed in a list next to it.

Here's the code :

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
 */
function ta_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

   // If the form is the user_register form
    if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
        // Attach our custom validation function as the first validation function
        array_unshift($form['#validate'], '_ta_module_user_validate');
        // Hide the email address field
        $form['account']['mail']['#type'] = 'hidden';
        // Give the email address field a random default value (in this case a random number and a timestamp)
        // as we cannot unset it due to Drupal's validation rules
        $form['account']['mail']['#default_value'] = rand(1111, 9999) . '@' .time() . '.com';
        // Add our new text entry field
        $form['mail_first'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Email address'),
      '#default_value' => '',
      '#size' => 35,
      '#maxlength' => 64,
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
        // Add our select list of possible email domain values
        $form['mail_last'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => 'Domaine',
      '#title_display' => 'before',
      '#options' => array(
              // These are the possible email address domains
              'myentreprise.net' => '@myentreprise.net',
              'myentreprise.com' => '@myentreprise.com',
            ),
      '#default_value' => 'myentreprise.net',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );
    }
}

/**
 * Function to piece together our email address
 */
function _ta_module_user_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // If our two form elements have values
    if (!empty($form_state['values']['mail_first']) && !empty($form_state['values']['mail_last'])) {
        // Set the email address to the correct value
        $form_state['complete form']['account']['mail']['#value'] = $form_state['input']['mail_first'] . '@' . $form_state['input']['mail_last'];
    }
}
```

(see [This Q/A](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/how-do-i-restrain-domain-names-of-e-mails-in-the-drupal-registration-form) for more infos).

All appear quite brightly, but when the user click on "create a new account", the user is created but the last function of my module doesn't work : the e-mail finally saved is the default value (something like 0129A@I1I101IZ10IZ.com) instead of the two pieces joined together...

**HOW TO FIX THIS : Thus how to assign to mail the value of mail-first + mail-last ?**

/!\ I'm working on Drupal 7, so I think it's an issue of uncorrect variables...

Thks for reading !  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to set the value for the form field used to contain the email address, then you should use code similar to the following one:

```
function _ta_module_user_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['mail_first']) && !empty($form_state['values']['mail_last'])) {
    form_set_value($form['account']['mail'], $form_state['values']['mail_first'] . '@' . $form_state['values']['mail_last'], $form_state);
  }
}
```

As an example of how `form_set_value()` is used, see [system_site_information_settings_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.admin.inc/function/system_site_information_settings_validate/7), which contains the following code:

```
// Check for empty front page path.
if (empty($form_state['values']['site_frontpage'])) {
  // Set to default "node".
  form_set_value($form['front_page']['site_frontpage'], 'node', $form_state);
}
else {
  // Get the normal path of the front page.
  form_set_value($form['front_page']['site_frontpage'], drupal_get_normal_path($form_state['values']['site_frontpage']), $form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$form_state['complete form']['account']['mail']['#value'] = $form_state['input']['mail_first'] . '@' . $form_state['input']['mail_last'];
```

Try using the [form_set_value()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_value/7) function.  Documentation says:

Use this function to change the submitted value of a form element in a form validation function, so that the changed value persists in $form_state through to the submission handlers.

Comment: Ok, thks! So I put something like : 

`form_set_value($form_state['mail'], $form_state['input']['mail_first'].$form_state['input']['mail_last'], $form_state);`

OR 

`form_set_value($element['#mail'], $form_state['input']['mail_first'].$form_state['input']['mail_last'], $form_state);`

???

Comment: Please see the form_set_value() documentation as I've never had to use the function myself.  And don't forget to concatenate your '@' sign to the email string.

Comment: I've tried both after reading the documentation. But the two times I got the following error : 
Notice : Undefined variable: element dans _`_ta_module_user_validate() (line 49 in /**DRUPAL_ROOT**/sites/all/modules/ta_module/ta_module.module).
Recoverable fatal error : Argument 2 passed to drupal_array_set_nested_value() must be an array, null given, called in /homepages/19/d362299801/htdocs/technomaide/includes/form.inc on line 2393 and defined dans drupal_array_set_nested_value() (ligne 6263 dans /homepages/19/d362299801/htdocs/technomaide/includes/common.inc).`_