# how to change "username" text located in registration form

Tags: users

how i can change "username" text, located in registration form.. i need to change it to "Organization Name" and everywhere of my website "username" text should replace with "Organization Name". How to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way to modify the user registration form is to add a hook_form_alter() function to your theme to change the form variables and add a theme hook to use a custom use-register.tpl.php file. There are numerous tutorials and responses here on stackexchange ([for example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/theming-the-user-registration-form)) that can guide you on this process, but if all you're trying to change is one string, you should try the [string overrides module](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides/), which allows you to easily replace anything passed through the t() function (ex. "username" --> "organization").